# How to remove element using specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html like this:

```
<html>
   <input type='button' name='button1' id='button1'>
   <input type='button' name='button2' id='button2'>
</html>
```

What I want to do that when User click **button2**, it should remove **button1** element and show a message on its place. It will look like this after **button2** click event.

```
<html>
   Button1 Removed
   <input type='button' name='button2' id='button2'>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jquery, you can do that:

```
$('#button2').click(function() {
  $('#button1').replaceWith('Button1 Removed')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery with an embedded function that can also do other things.

```
$('#button2').click(function() {  $('#button1').remove().html('<p>Button 1 Removed</>')  });
```

Remember its good practice to always enclose text in some tags like   etc

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $("#button1").replaceWith("<div>Hi der</div>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were using jquery then this solution:

```
$('#button2').click(function(){
  $('#button1').replaceWith('<p>Button1 Removed</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#button1').click(function() { 
 $('this').remove().html('<p>Button 1 Removed</>') 
 alert('button1 removed'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#button1").replaceWith("Button1 Removed");
    });
});
```